# UFW keep blocking IPsec

Tags: firewall, ufw, ipsec

I'm trying to run ikev2 VPN server on Ubuntu 16.
UFW list contains:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        69.xxx.xxx.91
Anywhere                   DENY        91.xxx.0.0/16
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere
110                        ALLOW       Anywhere
95                         ALLOW       Anywhere
465                        ALLOW       Anywhere
4190                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
1194                       ALLOW       Anywhere
500/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
4500/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
110 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
95 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
465 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4190 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1194 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
500/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4500/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But when I try to connect from client to my strongSwan (ikev2 VPN) server, I see the following in ufw log file:

```
Jan 19 11:38:58 puclm kernel: [2660918.033602] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=x4:xe:x8:xf:xa:1e:x4:0f:1b:7d:4e:38:08:x0 SRC=10.186.56.164 DST=192.168.1.51 LEN=632 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=31884 PROTO=UDP SPT=500 DPT=500 LEN=612
```

It's just beyond my understanding! If I turn off ufw, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW:

> **Default rules are fine for the average home user**
>   When you **turn UFW on**, it uses a default set of rules (**profile**) that should be fine for the average home user. That's at least the goal of the Ubuntu developers. In short, all 'incoming' is being denied, with some exceptions to make things easier for home users.

When working with `ufw` you should provide a very specific set of rules, that you would like to use. You might need to specifically add the connection details, which you want to use.

It seems that you'll have to choose between tweaking the `ufw` profile or manually setting up rules.

Assuming all you want to do is block incoming connections from **(1)** *69.xxx.xxx.91* and **(2)** *91.xxx.0.0/16* I suggest you drop the use of `ufw` and utilize `iptables` yourself.

Blocking traffic in the most simple way in `iptables` is done by variations of the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

More information can be found here: [Ubuntu IPtables How-To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) and here: [IPtables Examples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)